# How to design for a spectrum analyzer analysis?

Tags: rf, circuit-design, spectrum-analyzer

I am designing a board that I will eventually  have to hook up to a tracking spectrum analyzer to tune the PI circuit on.

I have 2 different circuits. The first goes `RF-OUT -> PI circuit -> U.FL connector -> external antenna`, and the second goes `RF-OUT -> PI circuit -> U.FL connector -> On board antenna`

In the board design, I assume because I am going to use a tracking generator on a spectrum analyzer that I need 2 U.FL connectors per line, so that I can hook up the analzyer.

Where would I put them? My instinct is to go `RF-OUT -> U.FL connector (for testing) -> PI circuit -> U.FL connector`

Comment: How are you switching antenna ? Physical or Pin diodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you would include a stripline Directional Coupler to antenna port on PCB so you can detect Return loss and output power with a pin diode peak detector to DMM using  sweep test pattern on your radio.  Then you don't need an SA and you have a built-in test method.  We call this Design for Testability (DFT) which is a MUST HAVE for any design, not an afterthought!!

You might use this on your prototype.

[image]

Normally directional coupler (splitters) are used for this. You can choose the coupling factor to minimize loss like -20 dB sample ports so insertion loss is low.  So if you are ok with this, look for microstrip or stripline DC-20. These have 4 ports on PCB and you you have 2 U.FL ports for the DC-20 and 1 for the External Antenna. If you choose to use only 3 of 4 ports and antenna port as the output then the DC-20 is terminated with 50R on the unused port.

### Advice.

You need a minimum number of accessories.  U.FL to SMA to N cables

Do a tolerance analysis on your RF PCB design. dielectric k has a wide tolerance as well as track tolerance on impedance.  Testing at board shop includes test coupons is about >100$  This allows them to control your designated track impedances with TDR testing and the tune G codes for give batch of laminate to obtain this result.

Learn "What is a Directional Coupler?" and how to measure Return Loss with it. such as for antenna. without spending $600 ( research)

Semi-rigid coax works best after calibration using SMA . learn to make.... later
If Analyzer has only 1 port then save gen response and then normalize when reading DUT response to get ratio.

Since s11 input impedance may be not 50 Ohms, the transfer function will then depend on source impedance so ratios must consider this using directional couplers... aka splitter

### Bonus.

make/buy?

design these loop antenna for EMI nearfield noise detection.
[image]

ref info: http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/rf_design_guidelines_semtech.pdf
https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no clue what your answer means. I am very new to RF. Could you please explain a bit more. What would an actual test setup look like with a spectrum analyzer and tracking generator? Also what is a DUT?

Comment: Device under test (DUT)  are U using good quality U.FL to SMA adapters for Analyzer?  SMA splitters are easy to find on search engine

Comment: You are new. DUT means "Device Under Test".

Comment: Okay just to make sure I am understanding (Thank you so much for working with me here!), there is only one wire going to the DUT, and I should put that wire where I would plug in the antenna.

Comment: Also, not sure if it matters, I have the SSA3021X on order as my spectrum analyzer.

Comment: I hope you got a calibration kit and tracking gen options.. you have lots to learn about calibrations.. and how to use ..not hard but necessary  look for how to from Agilent and other sources.. http://www.saelig.com/product/rbssa3x20.htm this is a directional coupler built to precision mechanics ... like 0.01% tolerances thus expensive.  But you might read on how to do it cheap with gen to antenna out and another antenna or 1/4W wire to input.  then insert filter but you need adapters rated for >3GHz  from U.FL to SMA to N(male)   Pasternack cables probably ok for 2Ghz,cheap ,poor for 10GHz

Comment: accessories http://www.siglent.com/ENs/prodcut-detailxx.aspx?id=1299&T=2&tid=18

Comment: start reading http://www.siglent.com/ENs/dow.aspx?u=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zaWdsZW50YW1lcmljYS5jb20vVVNBX3dlYnNpdGVfMjAxNC9Eb2N1bWVudHMvVXNlck1hbnVhbC9TU0EzMDAwWF9Vc2VyIE1hbnVhbF9VTTA3MDNYX0UwMkIucGRm

Comment: Agilent was HP and is now Keysight  (FYI)